# c++ memset cause segment fault of int** pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, memset

```
    int **dpTable = new int* [iMatrixHeight + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < iMatrixHeight + 1; i++)
    {
        dpTable[i] = new int [iMatrixWidth + 1];
    }

    memset(dpTable, 0, (sizeof(int)) * (iMatrixHeight + 1)*(iMatrixWidth + 1));
```

I'm using operator new to allocate a two-dimensional array, but if I use memset to initialize the array, I got a segmentfault when I access the array later. Without the memset, it's ok.

Am I doing anything wrong?
THX!

Comment: you're trying to fill an array of pointers with an array of integers, and you're overshooting by a factor of (iMatrixWidth + 1) (+/- the difference between pointer size and int).

Comment: You're using `memset` to obliterate the entire sequence of pointers your for-loop just worked so hard to acquire. (and breaching the sequence in the process just to add salt to the wound).

Comment: Another question I'd ask is what's the intended purpose for the +1. Why not just set iMetrixHeight accordingly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize a double pointer with zeros in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226696/initialize-a-double-pointer-with-zeros-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrays dpTable[i] do not point to contiguous memory. You have to initialize then one by one

```
for (int i = 0; i < iMatrixHeight + 1; i++)
{
    dpTable[i] = new int [iMatrixWidth + 1];
    memset(dpTable[i], 0, (iMatrixWidth + 1) * sizeof(int)) ;
}
```

Comment: Simply `dpTable[i] = new int [iMatrixWidth + 1]();` will work as well, if the OP has anything closely resembling a modern C++ compiler. No memset required in that case.

Comment: Oh yes, it suddenly struck me

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this code:

```
int **dpTable = new int* [iMatrixHeight + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < iMatrixHeight + 1; i++)
{
    dpTable[i] = new int [iMatrixWidth + 1];
}

memset(dpTable, 0, (sizeof(int)) * (iMatrixHeight + 1)*(iMatrixWidth + 1));
```

… you can do this:

```
int **dpTable = new int* [iMatrixHeight + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < iMatrixHeight + 1; i++)
{
    dpTable[i] = new int [iMatrixWidth + 1]();
}
```

Look ma, no `memset` – instead asking for zeroing of the memory.

Still that's very ugly in C++.

So, do this:

```
vector<vector<int>> table( iMatrixHeight + 1, vector<int>( iMatrixWidth + 1 ) );
```

where `vector` is `std::vector`.

Or, consider defining a matrix class with just a single `vector` as backing store.

Or just use an existing matrix class, e.g. from Boost.